# Continue tracking mouse with Pygame even when Pygame window isn't active

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Okay, so I'm using Pygame, and I created a code that tracks the mouse on my Pygame display.  However, when I pull up another window over the Pygame one, it stops tracking the mouse position.  I was wondering, is there any way to continue tracking the mouse even when my Pygame window is not the active one?

Comment: Where are you running your code in?

Comment: I'm just running it in IDLE.  Will it make a difference?

Comment: Would a certain compiler work better?  Or do I have to make it into an exe?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured it out.  I was going about it the wrong way.

`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`
is what I was using, and that only tracks the position of the mouse *on the Pygame surface created*.  So if there's another window there, the mouse isn't actually on the Pygame surface.  I ended up installing the module "win32api" and using

`import win32api
mouse = win32api.GetCursorPos()
x1 = mouse[0]
y1 = mouse[1]`

for the x and y coordinates of the mouse position *on the computer display*.  I realized afterward that there were questions answering what I needed to know, I just wasn't asking quite the right question.